# Angular-CLI: How to use `ng build --prod` command for with environment.staging.ts?

Tags: angular

I have 3 environment files. `environment.prod.ts`, `environment.staging.ts`, and `environment.ts`. I want to run `ng build --prod` but using `environment.staging.ts` instead of `environment.prod.ts`. So I thought I could do `ng build --environment=staging --aot --build-optimizer`. But I realised it did not copy ngsw-worker.js to /dist.

The command `ng build --prod` place a ngsw-worker.js inside /dist. However, `ng build` itself does not. Therefore, how can I use `ng build --prod` and tell this command to point to `environment.staging.ts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update (October 2018)**: Angular changed the parameter name. It's not `--environment` anymore, but `--configuration` now.

---

There are two different parameters: The build target (`--prod` is an alias for `--target=production`) and the build environment (set using `--environment`).

You can set the environment independently of the target. So what you can do is:

`ng build --prod --environment staging`

With that, you'll have a production build (with all the things that come with that, for example your service worker JS) with the environment variables from your `environment.staging.ts`.

Comment: do I need --environment=staging  or just --environment staging?

Comment: Both work. `ng build --help` prints the version without `=`.

Comment: environment staging or environment=staging don't work. Use --configuration=staging